# Race Around Condition in PHP And MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Everyone i was wondering if there was any difference between the following two codes meaning that the if any of the following code can result in racearound condition if so then how can we check this...

```
$data = mysqli_query($con, "select max(id) from sometable");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
$id="ABCID";
$uid = $row[0]+1;
$id .= $id.$uid;
mysqli_query($con, "insert into sometable values('$id')");
echo "Your Id is ".$id ;
```

And The Second Code is As Follows:

```
mysqli_query($con, "insert into  sometable values("//user details")");
$data = mysqli_query($con, "select * from sometable where emailid='$_POST['emailid']'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
$id="ABCID";
$uid = $row['id'];
$id .= $id.$uid;
echo "Your Id is ".$id ;
```

the above two codes are working fine but i wanted to know that which method is best..

Comment: Both are open to SQL injection; so, no difference.

Comment: hmmm i was looking for some other answer, not related to security

Comment: well first is select query and second is update query and both code is not safe

Comment: i was wondering if first code could create confliction in generating unique id or not

Answer (score 1):

The first method is open to race condition problems. What if two scripts are running in parallel (very common scenario for a web server) and essentially perform these operations:

```
a   = SELECT MAX(..)
b   = SELECT MAX(..)
aid = a + 1
bid = b + 1
```

They both produce the same "uid".

That's why the second method is better; you should always let the database generate the id internally, since it has mechanisms that specifically deal with concurrency issues.

---

Having said that, lots of SQL injection vulnerabilities in both examples; I hope this is just an illustrative sample and not real code.

Comment: Good to hear. BTW, one of the primary reasons your question is being downvoted is that it's not helpful to future visitors. Imagine anyone trying to find an answer for the same problem and googling around. They won't find this question, because its title and description is terrible. Try to formulate a better question with this scenario in mind; describe better what it is you're asking without requiring anyone to read the code in detail to understand your issue.